# Mobile web site - explicit save button or implicit save?

Tags: android, mobile, user-interface, web

I understand that there is a convention for mobile apps (e.g. see here: [Explicit save vs. implicit save - what to prefer when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027188/explicit-save-vs-implicit-save-what-to-prefer-when)) that says that you shouldn't use an explicit 
Save button (as you would for a desktop application) but rather save the data by default, and use the mobile device's Back button as cancel.

Since I'm developing a mobile *web site* rather than an app, I'm wondering if it is customary (or even: *a good idea*) to keep in line with this convention or not, i.e. if I should use an explicit Save button or use an implicit save?

On one hand, because it is used on a mobile device, there might be the expectation that all data is automatically saved and users may lose data if they forget to press the save button.
On the other hand it is far more complicated to implement an implicit save on a web page, because it most likely means that you'll have to send a stream of updates to the server as the user enters his data.

Are there any guidelines regarding this topic, and what do you use when developing a mobile site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your program is a website and not an App, most users will use the Back button to go back to the previous page. I suggest you should add a save button since most people are used to seeing them on websites, and will treat your site as such.

thanks,
Alex M